# How to loop my countdown timer in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, timer, countdown

I'm trying to loop my timer, so it would show me how many seconds are left. Right now it only shows me how many seconds are left **from the moment of starting a script**, but I would like it to change every second. **I'm going to run this script 24/7**, so I need real time result.

My timer:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import time


x = datetime.now()
y=x.replace(hour=12, minute=0, second=0)
t=y-x
secs=t.seconds
```

I was thinking about while loop, but I don't know how to use it in this code. If you want you can change my timer **I only want it to tell me how many seconds are left to designated time.**

***How I solved it:***

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import time


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    x=datetime.today()
    y=x.replace(hour=17, minute=10, second=0)
    t=y-x
    secs=t.seconds
```

Comment: What do you mean by "would show me how many seconds are left"? Print?something Like a loop that print evert secend?

Comment: If you just want how many seconds pass: ```from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

old_time = datetime.now()
sleep(5) # pass time...
print((datetime.now() - old_time).seconds)```. that is your intentions?

Comment: Alternatively for a per second output `while t > 0: print(t, datetime.now()); t -= 1; time.sleep(1)`

Comment: I'm going to use it in my Discord Bot, so I can't use **time.sleep()**, because it will freeze rest of the code @BBQuercus.

Comment: @RiveN So run it on a thread

Comment: For example I want to send **Hello!** on Discord channel everyday at 7 a.m. So I need countdown to 7 a.m.

Comment: It's probably easier to just check the time in a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time, datetime

designated_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 15, 8, 24) # designated_date
designated_time = time.mktime(designated_date.timetuple()) # designated unix time in seconds

while True:
    time.sleep(1)         # 1 second delay
    current_time = int(time.time())      # every second get current unix time
    left = designated_time - current_time # calculation how much seconds left to desingated time
    print(left) # print results
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you could provide some explanation along with code in your answer, just a tip!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

It "say" "Hello!" every day in 4:20. You need to call `time_to_sleep` or run it on a thread. Also, you may change to your time (`HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND`) and frequency in days (`NEXT_DAY`)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from time import sleep
HOUR = 4
MINUTE = 20
SECOND = 0
NEXT_DAY = 1

def time_to_sleep():
    a = datetime.now()
    a += timedelta(days=NEXT_DAY)

    a = a.replace(hour=HOUR, minute=MINUTE, second=SECOND)

    return (a - datetime.now()).total_seconds()

# you may wont to run this on a thread 
def your_print():
    while True:
        sleep(time_to_sleep())
        print("Hello!")
```